# Python filter gives empty dataframe along with the filtered rows

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am doing basic filter on a python dataframe.Below is the code.

```
df1 = df.loc[df['ID'] == '2f45b-ii58-4927']
print(df1)
```

It gives me empty dataframe along with the filtered rows like below.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []

     Date  sal       ID
0  14Jun   10100  2f45b-ii58-4927
```

I don t need the empty dataframe part along with the filtered rows .Is there any way to achieve this. The reason I do not need the empty dataframe part is I am calling this python function in a Azure function. The Python function will read the json files recursively from azure storage into a dataframe, filter the dataframe and gives the output. If the filtered row is not from the first file the function read, the Azure function gives output as []

Thank you.

Edit:
Below is the code.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
import json
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import datetime
import uuid

filename = "raw/filename.json"

container_name="test"
constr = ""

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(constr)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(filename)
streamdownloader = blob_client.download_blob()

fileReader = json.loads(streamdownloader.readall())
df = pd.DataFrame(fileReader)
df1= df[df['ID'] == '2f45b-ii58-4927']
df1.head()
```

Below is the output.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date,sal,ID]
Index: []

     Date  sal       ID
0  14Jun   10100  2f45b-ii58-4927
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `loc`, you should do a direct filtering of the `DataFrame`:

```py
df1 = df[df['ID'] == '2f45b-ii58-4927']
print(df1)
```

Since `loc` tries to find the location of the items in a Boolean (`True`/`False`) object inside the square braces, it is not able to locate the exact item as a `DataFrame`.

Comment: I tried this too, it didn't work.

Comment: Please show the exact output/error you are receiving with this.

Comment: Also if possible, @SanjanaSanju, please provide a reproducible example, a sample that can get the dataframe created.

Comment: I have edited the question with the code and the output.

Comment: Thank you, can you also please show me what does `df.head()` too? Would like to see the structure of the original dataframe being constructed via json and also `df.dtypes`, since I suspect may e the ID column is being read as an object instead of string

Comment: from df.types, the ID is of object dtype. Strings in python are stored as object because the length of the string varies. I even tried to change the datatype to string,still same result.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below and it worked for me.

```
if not dfl.empty:
print(df1)
```